# Quasar Q-Table getting value of selected column data

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm trying to get the selected column data of an array from a Q-Table. I'm using the example from https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#selection from its codepen, I'd like to Display only the "Name" column value under it. I tried using `{{ selected.name }}` but nothing is being displayed

here's the codepen link https://codepen.io/jake-stewart-go/pen/yLvojLW?editors=101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this codepen.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/JjpyBXq?editors=101

You need to check the length and then display the name property.

It's single select you can directly take 0 `index` and then name